# Removing WiFi Network from Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

Does anyone know how to remove a WiFi network from Google Glass? My WiFi at work wants you to consent to a privacy policy which Glass can not accept so I don't get a data connection. When I tether it to my phone, it keeps reverting back to the work WiFi network. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say ask google, as I doubt there are enough people on this site with Glass to help you out.

Comment: This question doesn't even remotely belong here

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can try.

1)  Go to Glass ->> Settings -> Wifi -> Forget.

2) In the My Glass app, pair your device, select Wi-Fi, select the network you want to use.

3)  Good Old Factory reset.

Also, as per a commenter above - this Doesn't belong here at all.

Answer (score 0):

For questions such as this, your best bet is to [contact one of the Glass Guides](https://www.google.com/glass/help/), either by email or phone. They can talk you through the process or help with any other problems you may have. Make sure you have your ID ready (the one they sent you as part of the invite).